# Remove a Class from Class List JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, dom

I'm trying to remove the "DayPicker-Day--selected" class with the below code, but it isn't doing it. Anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```js
      let sameDayChoice = document.getElementsByClassName(
        'DayPicker-Day DayPicker-Day--end DayPicker-Day--selected DayPicker-Day--today',
      );
      for (let i = 0; i < sameDayChoice.length; i++) {
        sameDayChoice[i].classList.remove('DayPicker-Day--selected');
      }
```

Comment: have you checked if sameDayChoice is returning the expected result? You have a very long class selector there make sure there's no mistake there

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an Html Collection.You need to convert it into an array.You can use Array.from

```
let sameDayChoice = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(
        'DayPicker-Day DayPicker-Day--end DayPicker-Day--selected DayPicker-Day--today',
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a filter:

```
const removeClass = 'DayPicker-Day--selected';
const newSameDayChoice = sameDayChoice.filter(class => class !== removeClass);
```

newSameDayChoice should return without 'DayPicker-Day--selected'.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the 'DayPicker-dat--selected' than select all classes with that classname and remove it .

```js
let sameDayChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("DayPicker-Day--selected");
    for (let i = 0; i < sameDayChoice.length; i++) {
      sameDayChoice[i].classList.remove("DayPicker-Day--selected");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a live HTMLCollection; which means that when you remove the class-name by which the element was selected from an element then that element is itself no longer in the NodeList, which means that every time you remove the class-name the index – `i` – is no longer an accurate index of the next element in the NodeList.

Simple illustration of the problem:

```js
let divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('div');

for (let i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
  divElements[i].classList.remove('div');
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2em;
}

.div.card {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.card::after {
  content: " (" attr(class) ")";
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div card">card: 1</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 2</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 3</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 4</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 5</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 6</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 7</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 8</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 9</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 10</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 11</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 12</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 13</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 14</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 15</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 16</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 17</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 18</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 19</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 20</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 21</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 22</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 23</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 24</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 25</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 26</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 27</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 28</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 29</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 30</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9shf2nvg/).

The easiest way to do this would be to either switch to using a while loop:

```js
let divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('div');

// here, while the divElements HTMLCollection has a
// first-element, the while list continues, and removes
// the relevant class-name from the classList:
while (divElements[0]) {
  divElements[0].classList.remove('div');
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2em;
}

.div.card {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.card::after {
  content: " (" attr(class) ")";
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div card">card: 1</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 2</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 3</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 4</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 5</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 6</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 7</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 8</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 9</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 10</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 11</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 12</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 13</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 14</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 15</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 16</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 17</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 18</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 19</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 20</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 21</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 22</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 23</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 24</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 25</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 26</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 27</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 28</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 29</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 30</div>
</div>
```

Or convert the NodeList to an Array, which creates a static list of elements, and opens up `Array.prototype` methods, such as `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

Using a static `Array`:

```js
// here we use Array.from() to convert the iterable HTMLCollection
// into an Array, which 'freezes' the collection as the Array isn't
// updated by the removal of elements from the HTMLCollection:
let divElements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('div'));

for (let i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
  divElements[i].classList.remove('div');
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2em;
}

.div.card {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.card::after {
  content: " (" attr(class) ")";
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div card">card: 1</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 2</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 3</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 4</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 5</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 6</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 7</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 8</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 9</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 10</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 11</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 12</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 13</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 14</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 15</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 16</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 17</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 18</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 19</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 20</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 21</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 22</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 23</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 24</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 25</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 26</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 27</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 28</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 29</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 30</div>
</div>
```

Or, using `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```js
let divElements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('div'));

// here we use Array.prototype.forEach(), along with an Arrow
// function to remove the 'div' class-name from the element's
// classList; 'divEl' is a reference to the current element-node
// of the Array over which we're iterating:
divElements.forEach(
  (divEl) =>  divEl.classList.remove('div')
);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2em;
}

.div.card {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.card::after {
  content: " (" attr(class) ")";
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div card">card: 1</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 2</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 3</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 4</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 5</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 6</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 7</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 8</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 9</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 10</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 11</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 12</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 13</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 14</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 15</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 16</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 17</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 18</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 19</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 20</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 21</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 22</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 23</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 24</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 25</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 26</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 27</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 28</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 29</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 30</div>
</div>
```

Of course, if instead of `getElementsByClassName()` you used `querySelectorAll()`, you could take advantage of the `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` method:

```js
// here we use document.querySelectorAll(), which returns
// a static NodeList, so the NodeList doesn't become updated
// once the class - by which the element is selected - is
// removed from the element:
let divElements = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

// using NodeList.prototype.forEach(), identically to our
// use of Array.prototype.forEach():
divElements.forEach(
  (divEl) => divEl.classList.remove('div')
);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2em;
}

.div.card {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.card::after {
  content: " (" attr(class) ")";
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div card">card: 1</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 2</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 3</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 4</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 5</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 6</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 7</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 8</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 9</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 10</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 11</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 12</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 13</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 14</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 15</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 16</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 17</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 18</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 19</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 20</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 21</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 22</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 23</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 24</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 25</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 26</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 27</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 28</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 29</div>
  <div class="div card">card: 30</div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).
- [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).